# Retrieve storage policies for each Virtual Machine's VirtualDisk

Tags: python, vmware, vsphere, pyvmomi

I'm using pyVmomi to pull a list of all VM's in our VMware vSphere environment.

I'm iterating through the [VirtualMachine](https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#/doc/vim.VirtualMachine.html) *config.hardware.device* and checking if I have an instance of *vim.vm.device.VirtualDisk*

```
for device in virtual_machine.config.hardware.device:
    if isinstance(device, vim.vm.device.VirtualDisk):
        # Collect information here
```

Is it possible with pyVmomi to retrieve the storage policies from a VirtualMachine or do I need to work backwards from each [Datastore](https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#/doc/vim.Datastore.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use [this example](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/list_vm_storage_policy.py) from the `pyvmomi` examples which shows details on all of the storage policies of the VM.
There is also the [Storage Policy API docs](https://code.vmware.com/apis/206/storage-policy) if you need more reference.

Best of luck.